# What image dimensions to choose for mobile and desktop in 2015?

Tags: resolution, mobile, image-format, dimensions

I am working on a portfolio website for a friend showcasing the work in a gallery with photoswipe.com.

Just got the original photos delivered. They are between 70 and 100 mb and range from 2551x5124 to 3588x3574 in TIFF format with almost no photo having the same dimension.

Now first of all I need to convert those to png and then I need to choose the dimensions I want these in. And what dimensions do I need for mobile and desktop in 2015?

With this CSS chart mind https://deviceatlas.com/blog/most-popular-smartphone-screen-resolutions-2015 as well as this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions in mind

for mobile I would opt for 360x640.

For tablet I would choose 1024x768 or 1200x800 (with increasing screen sizes in mind)

and for desktop 1600x1200.

Does that make sense?

For the retina screens do I need to double the dimensions with this older post in mind netvlies.nl/blog/design-interactie/retina-revolution ?

Sorry I am very new to all this but I know I like the port to load super fast and therefore optimized images and the right dimensions are top priority for me. Though not sure where to start?

Are my rough guesses somewhat OK? What dimensions do you use? Using BS [What's the width to mockup websites for desktop and mobile now?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56301/whats-the-width-to-mockup-websites-for-desktop-and-mobile-now) are their dimensions applicable to images as well perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the width to mockup websites for desktop and mobile now?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56301/whats-the-width-to-mockup-websites-for-desktop-and-mobile-now)